# Create custom map with osmosis for android mapsforge

Tags: openstreetmap, mapsforge, osmosis

Following this guide (https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/wiki/GettingStartedMapWriter#Examples), I can create now maps in format .map to be used with android mapsforge libraries.

The question is: is possible to create custom maps with osmosis and mapsforge map-writer in terms of selected objects? I mean, is possible to create maps that not include the buildings, for example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The link of the guide has moved here: https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Map-Writer.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, osmosis can filter for tags. You can accept or reject specific tags as well as specific elements. See [example usage](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage) in the OSM wiki as well as the [detailed usage instructions](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Detailed_Usage).